# Type of smoker and location

Tags: equipment

Can I place a vertical propane smoker on my patio? I would like to smoke fish, veggies and meat in vertical smoker. Can I place the smoker on my patio?

Comment: Welcome to seasoned advice!  You need to give us more information to answer your question: what kind of patio?  enclosed or open?  what's it made of? How big of a smoker?

Comment: Also: are you worried about fire safety, or some other issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details. Check [ask] to learn more. Otherwise, why would you not be able to put a smoker in your patio?